# How to write my SQL query?

Tags: sql

Please help in making SQL query, here I have a table where I have:

> ID, Type, Amount, Date column.

Here I need IDs which have cheque converted to DD ie I need to select ID 1001 & 1004 (as cheque which is converted to DD - Dates might be same).

```
ID      Type       Amount   Date 
--------------------------------------
1001    Cheque       100    27-09-2014
1001    DD           200    28-09-2014
1002    DD           200    28-09-2014 
1003    DD           400    28-09-2014 
1003    Cheque       500    28-09-2014
1004    Cheque       500    28-09-2014
1004    DD           500    28-09-2014
```

Comment: How - when the rows have the same date and there's nothing other obvious to order by - do you know which happens first, the cheque or the DD?

Comment: You should show what you already tried and ask for specific help, not for others to solve the problem for you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

If you need `id`s with both `cheque` and `dd`, you can do so with aggregation and a `having` clause.  It think this will work:

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having min(case when type = 'Cheque' then date end) < min(case when type = 'DD' then date end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presume Table name is TN, try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM TN WHERE Type = 'DD' and ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TN WHERE Type = 'Cheque')
```